# Upgrade of Jenkins from UI when running as war

Tags: java, jenkins

I am hosting Jenkins with one master and two slaves.

Started jenkins as java process

```
nohup java -jar jenkins.war -Dhudson.model.ParametersAction.keepUndefinedParameters=true --httpPort=8091 > jenkins.log 2>&1 &
```

Now , I am trying to upgrade jenkins from UI.

Is it possible to upgrade jenkins automatically from UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Click Manage Jenkins and, if there's an update available, you will see an upgrade notification at the top, and an <kbd>Update automatically</kbd> button.

Once the updated WAR file has been downloaded, there should be a <kbd>Restart</kbd> button on that page next time you visit.

Comment: Thank you. The upgraded war will it also replaces older one?

Comment: Yes, it replaces the existing WAR. Though Jenkins remembers the previous version number, and gives the possibility to downgrade to that version again (by automatically downloading the old WAR).

Comment: I am seeing New version of Jenkins (2.220) is available, but no Update automatically button

Comment: @AshishKarpe, Refer to this answer to see the button
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36503130/5777388